# Solution for problem 3 in google code jam 2019

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried solving the google code jam question "Cryptopangrams" yesterday. I was able to pass the example cases, but my solution was not accepted.

The problem statement can be found here:
https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051705/000000000008830b

I tried to find the factors of the number using traditional methods (pollard rho seemed to be overkill for the constraints) and then sorted all the unique factors into a list. There is a one to one correspondence between the letters of the alphabet and the elements in the list.

So then, i substituted the letters into the products, and returned the string.

The code worked when i tried it on my laptop, when i tested it against the two example cases given in the question, but failed when i uploaded it to the website.

```py
# Function to find the prime factors of n and returns them in a list
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors

# Gets number of cases
cases = int(input())

for case in range(cases):
    text = ''
    alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    ch = input().split()
    no_of_chars = int(ch[1])
    max_prime = int(ch[0])

    # gets products from input
    products = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

    flag = None
    factors = []
    pairs = []

    # For loop to find factors and append them to pairs
    for i in range(len(products)):
        l = prime_factors(products[i])
        a, b = l[0], l[1]
        if i > 0:
            if pairs[i-1][1] == a:
                flag = True
            # Swaps elements of pair if not in linked order
            else:
                a, b = b, a
        pairs.append([a, b])

        # Adds new factors to list
        if a in factors:
            flag = True
        else:
            factors.append(a) 

        if b in factors:
            flag = False
        else:
            factors.append(b)

    # Sorts the factors
    factors.sort()
    for i in pairs:
        text += alphabets[factors.index(i[0])]
    text += alphabets[factors.index(pairs[-1][1])]
    # Prints output in the required format
    print('Case #{}: {}'.format(case + 1, text.upper())
```

On my laptop, given the input (copy-pasted from : https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051705/000000000008830b)

```
2
103 31
217 1891 4819 2291 2987 3811 1739 2491 4717 445 65 1079 8383 5353 901 187 649 1003 697 3239 7663 291 123 779 1007 3551 1943 2117 1679 989 3053
10000 25
3292937 175597 18779 50429 375469 1651121 2102 3722 2376497 611683 489059 2328901 3150061 829981 421301 76409 38477 291931 730241 959821 1664197 3057407 4267589 4729181 5335543
```

I am getting the output :

```
Case #1: CJQUIZKNOWBEVYOFDPFLUXALGORITHMS
Case #2: SUBDERMATOGLYPHICFJKNQVWXZ
```

which is the same as given on the website.
But when i submitted it, i received the following message.

```
Wrong Answer! Test Set Skipped
```

Could anyone tell me where i went wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Check @Panguido answer for the clue: you might get consecutive numbers in your message. I think you'll need to find the first consecutive numbers that are not the same before solving.

Comment: check also https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/0000000000051705/analysis/000000000008830b

Answer (score 4):

```
1
107 29
15 15 15 15 21 49 77 143 221 323 437 667 899 1147 1517 1763 2021 2491 3127 3599 4087 4757 5183 5767 6557 7387 8633 9797 10403
Case #1: ABABACCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Try this test case.
In case you get wrong.
Explanation:
suppose semiprimes of form pq,pq,qr
if you decide to start with p then p,q,p but then this p will not divide qr;
if start with q,p,q,r ........right

So Logic is kept taking gcd of the first semiprime with other until you get gcd!=firstsemiprime, that gcd will your one prime at some position
then, iterate backwards and forward to get other primes.
For Solution:
https://shashankmishracoder.wordpress.com/2019/04/07/google-code-jam-2019-qualification-round-problem-c-cryptopangrams/

Answer (score 2):

My approach to the problem was using the fact that the numbers are prime. Now as we are given p1*p2 and p2*p3 we can get p2=gcd(p1*p2,p2*p3) and p1=p1*p2/gcd(p1*p2,p2*p3). The only condition necessary is that p1*p2!=p2*p3

Hence the code in python3 goes something like:

```
from math import gcd

T=int(input())
for t in range(T):
    N,M=map(int,input().split())
    l=list(map(int,input().split()))
    a=[0]*(M+1)
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[i]!=l[i+1]:
            a[i+1]=gcd(l[i],l[i+1])
            for j in range(i,-1,-1):
                a[j]=l[j]//a[j+1]
            for j in range(i+1,M):
                a[j+1]=l[j]//a[j]
    # print(a)
    b=sorted(list(set(a)))
    d={}
    for i in range(len(b)):
        d[b[i]]=chr(65+i)
    ans=""
    for i in a:
        ans+=d[i]
    print("Case #"+str(t+1)+":",ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even my solution didn't pass the system test. But I tried a different approach. Your code will definitely get a TLE because the constraints for 'n' is nˆ100.
Read the question carefully! Each number in the given array is a product of two primes. Say, for example, a,b,c are the primes. Now a[0] = a * b, a[1] = b * c.
Now, if you are able to determine 'b' then you can easily find a and c using normal division. The greatest common divisor of a[0] and a[1] is b!